# GridView with XML extraction

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

**User.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<users>
  <user id="1300" name="Cindy" password="1234" userType="borrower"/>
  <user id="1301" name="andy98" password="9999" userType="borrower"/>
  <user id="1302" name="Alex" password="alex99" userType="borrower"/>
  <user id="1399" name="admin" password="admin" userType="administrator"/>
</users>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("User.xml"));
gridView.DataSource = xmlList;
gridView.DataBind();
```

This will result the output which of all users, but I only want to output those `userType` who are `borrower`; How can I filter it this way? I tried to use below method, but nothing is happen.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("User.xml"));
XmlNodeList xmlList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("users/user[@userType='borrower']");
gridViewUser.DataSource = xmlList;
gridViewUser.DataBind();
```

**Default.aspx**

```
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Borrower Name" SortExpression="name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="Borrower ID" SortExpression="id" />
</Columns>
```

The output i expected for :

```
Borrower ID | Borrower Name
  Cindy     |  1300
  andy98    |  1301
  Alex      |  1302
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `/users` or `//users` in your xpath:

```
XmlNodeList xmlList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/users/user[@userType='borrower']");
```

Try `<asp:TemplateField>` instead of `<asp:BoundField>`, then you will need to format it in tabular form yourself by using `<asp:HeaderTemplate>, <asp:FooterTemplate>` something like:

```
<asp:HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>Borrower ID</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>Borrower Name</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
</asp:HeaderTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:FooterTemplate>
    </table>
</asp:FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output is not i expected. Further information had been provided.

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Xml.XmlElement' does not contain a property with the name 'id'. Any idea for this error?